# it can be possible add 1 button in image caption to get inquiry in form about this image when click on the button in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, image, contact-form-7, figcaption

i want to add a button in each image caption for the user in wordpress, so when user click on this button a contact form should be open or any form, and form contain this image url to submit data to us.  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dh9Od.png)

Comment: image example already attach

Comment: You could just append the button using javascript/jQuery.  Hard to give you a better or clearer answer without seeing any code or any examples.  Or it could be added by customizing the template that outputs that page - but no clue what you're working with so hard to give examples.